# Bridging edge loops - distorted

Tags: modeling, edges, loop

I'm currently trying to bridge the edge loops between my hand and arm. I have joined them so they are the same object, but the wrist appears all distorted when I bridge them. I have played around a bit, and they both have 16 vertices and are aligned.

Is there a way to do this so the connection appears a bit more smooth?

[image: hand with edge loop bridge]

[image: Hand connected in object mode]

Comment: your normals are inverted, maybe this is what you're talking about? Select all in Edit mode and press Shift N

Comment: try selecting the faces and press 'Shift+N' on your keyboard to recalculate the normals

Comment: @moonboots That worked, thanks so much

Comment: @Ribbit12 thank you!